# Error updating styles paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I want to update my styles in paperclip, but when i run the command, a error is returned. Here is the code of my styles:

image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
  validates_presence_of :image
  has_attached_file :image, :processors => [:ffmpeg],
    :styles => { :video => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'mp4' },
    :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100>", :format => 'jpg' },
    :large => { :geometry => "400x300>", :format => 'jpg' },
    :medium => { :geometry => "400x200>", :format => 'png' },
    :icon => { :geometry => "36x36>", :format => 'jpg' },
    :profile => { :geometry => "28x28>", :format => 'jpg' } },
    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

end
```

Returned Error:

```
Regenerating Image -> image -> [:icon, :large, :medium, :profile, :thumb, :video]
rake aborted!
Cocaine::CommandNotFoundError
```

How i solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you have not installed the "paperclip-ffmpeg" gem.

See this link: https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg#requirements